# whats the official github link for source code of apt

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt, package-managers, aptitude

I am having an older version of apt on the nfs mounted server, its version is around 0.6.x.
i want to update it to latest/newer version like 1.2.x. i wanted the link for the source code where can i get it and compile to have my local version of "apt"

exactly using ***apt-ftparchive*** for repo creation

the problem that i have with using the older ow is, if i created the packages locally it fails the installation on ubuntu 16.04 system.
It fails with **"Hash Sum Mismatch"**
where as if i do it using apt-1.2.x version i am able to configure the repo and install the package as well

i tried to google it, there were many cloned repo in github but i could not link to the official debian one.

any link which i can use (open-source) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any `Github` repository for `apt`, but instead you can use official guide how to get sources:

> 15.1.1. Getting the Sources

Rebuilding a Debian package starts with getting its source code. The easiest way is to use the `apt-get source source-package-name` command. This command requires a `deb-src` line in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and up-to-date index files (i.e. `apt-get update`). These conditions should already be met if you followed the instructions from the chapter dealing with APT configuration.

Note however, that you will be downloading the source packages from the `Debian` version mentioned in the `deb-src` line. If you need another version, you may need to download it manually from a `Debian` mirror or from the web site. This involves fetching two or three files (with extensions `*.dsc` — for Debian Source Control — `*.tar.comp`, and sometimes `*.diff.gz` or `*.debian.tar.comp` — comp taking one value among `gz`, `bz2` or `xz` depending on the compression tool in use), then run the `dpkg-source -x file.dsc` command.

If the `*.dsc` file is directly accessible at a given URL, there is an even simpler way to fetch it all, with the `dget URL` command. This command (which can be found in the devscripts package) fetches the `*.dsc` file at the given address, then analyzes its contents, and automatically fetches the file or files referenced within. Once everything has been downloaded, it extracts the source package (unless the `-d` or `--download-only` option is used).

Link to the documentation is [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/debian-packaging.en.html).

Comment: i did manage to dig out one git repo for it https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt, however i have still not tried it, will update whats the status once i try it out

Comment: Happy to hear it, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

On the official Debian Github account, I found this repo which has been archived but contains an updated version of apt :
https://github.com/Debian/apt